# How tween array into another array with different length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, canvas, data-visualization

I want to implement animation for a line in `<canvas>`. The line is defined as array of points `{x, y}`.

It is very easy to tween such array into another state with same length.

But how to deal with case where state on start and state on end have different lengths? For example I have a triangle (closed line) with points:

`[{x:0, y:0}, {x:0, y:10}, {x:10, y:10}]`

I want to animate this triangle into square with points:

`[{x:0, y:0}, {x:0, y:10}, {x:10, y:10}, {x:0, y:10}]`

Are there  any implementations or libs for such cases? Or any useful algorithm?

Comment: I think it matters how you want that animation to happen.  Should one point split into two?  Which point should split?  Should one point melt into the line while two new points are formed out of the adjacent lines?

Comment: Year. There are a lot of possible variants. Need simplest and elegant as possible. Just adding points into start state then tween will looks ugly. For case with triangle/square most beautiful case, I think, will be adding point into `{x:5, y:5}`, then tween it into `{x:0, y:10}`

Comment: Haven´t used it but http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html might help

Comment: And here is an example using css transition: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/mLnhbkL3/